# Programmatically get network statistics for a selected adapter

Tags: winapi, network-programming

I am trying to find a way to programmatically get the network statistics for a specific adapter in Windows 10. I found that GetIpStatistics() function, but it returns statistics for all adapters. Does anyone know of a function that gets the same type of statistics but only for a specific adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GetIfTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getiftable) or [`GetIfTable2()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-getiftable2), and then look for the desired interface in the returned table.

Or, if you already know the LUID/index of the desired interface, you can use [`GetIfEntry2()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-getifentry2) or [`GetIfEntry2Ex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-getifentry2ex) instead.

Comment: GetIfEntry2Ex() worked perfectly while processing the adapter information returned by GetAdaptersAddresses(). Thank you for your help, Remy. I really appreciate it.